# Binding the row color to a property (dependant on data in the row) in MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `datagrid` whose `itemsSource` is bound to a collection of `Customer` objects in my `ViewModel`.

Each `Customer` object has a property `IsComplete` (not a visible column in the datagrid) which is a boolean. How do I color the entire row red if `IsComplete` is false?

I am new to the MVVM concepts so I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around it. Examples I've seen so far don't seem to color the entire row depending on the contents of a single property.

I'm willing to refactor if that's what it takes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVVM style, create a CustomerViewModel and define property CustomerColor (related on IsComplete property value).

Try this:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding CustomerColor}"/>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still a bit confused:

- So it's okay to have multiple ViewModels for the same form?

- Do I then have to keep an ObservableCollection of CustomerViewModels somewhere? If so, then where? And how do I bind the data in each row to the Customer object contained within each CustomerViewModel?

Answer (score 2):

I would try using a [RowStyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyleselector.aspx) for this.  It allows you to define different row styles, and select one per row, depending on the data in that row.

Essentially, you define a class that inherits `StyleSelector`, and override the `SelectStyle` method.  That's where you put your logic to choose a style based on the row data -- `item` contains the row data:

```
public class MyStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is Customer)
        {
            return ((Customer)item).IsComplete ? 
                App.Current.Resources["RedRowStyle"] :
                App.Current.Resources["NormalRowStyle"]
        }
        return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
    }
}
```

Add the resources to your application's resource dictionary:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" x:Key="NormalRowStyle">
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource NormalRowStyle}" x:Key="RedRowStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then, you reference the selector via a static resource, something like:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyStyleSelector x:Key="MyStyleSelector" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <DataGrid RowStyleSelector="{StaticResource MyStyleSelector}">
        <!-- ... -->
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Great answer for more complicated scenarios